# Вывод продуктов в блоках построчно

Tags: html, css

Всем привет.

У меня такая проблемка. Для начала скриншот:

[image]

Как вы видите, у меня 4 товара в рядм, потом переходит на другую строчку, и опять 4 товара и т. д. Как сделать через таблицы, я знаю, делаю счетчик, если он равен 4, то добавляю `<tr>`, и пошло по второй строчке. А вот как сделать через Div? Помогите, очень нужно!

Примерная верстка:

```
<div style="float:left">1 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">2 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">3 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">4 товар</div>
<br>
<div style="float:left">5 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">6 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">7 товар</div>
<div style="float:left">8 товар</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из [простых способов](http://jsfiddle.net/e0Ljn99h/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>1 товар</div>
    <div>2 товар</div>
    <div>3 товар</div>
    <div>4 товар</div>
    <div>5 товар</div>
    <div>6 товар</div>
    <div>7 товар</div>
    <div>8 товар</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    letter-spacing: -.36em;
}
.wrapper > div {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* + вендорные префиксы */
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}
```

Можно так же использовать **display** со значениями **table | table-row | table-cell**

Comment: Уау, круто. Только могли бы объяснить, как он понимает, что надо перекидывать на другую строчку? Что это .wrapper > div?

Comment: @duddeniska, "оно" ничего не понимает ))) Мы для "оно" установили ширину в 25%, поэтому и четыре блока в одном ряду. Укажите 33.33% и будет три в ряду, 50% - два. Кстати, это можно использовать при адаптивном дизайне - переключать кол-во блоков для разных размеров видимой области.

Comment: Спасибо! И еще вопрос: для чего letter-spacing: -.36em;

Comment: @duddeniska, между элементами "inline-block" есть пустые текстовые узлы. Для людей несведущих, они образуют "*загадочные отступы*" между элементами. Отрицательный интервал между символами - это один из способов избавиться от таких отступов.

Comment: очень доходчиво